# Is there a way to compare a field's value to a parameter's value in jasperReport Expression Editor?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to print parts of a jasper report conditionally by comparing the parameter supplied value to the value in the field.

However, when I do the comparison the outcome is always `FALSE`. 
Both the field and the parameter are `INTEGERS`. If I compare either of them to an actual number that exists in the dataset,  then the outcome is `true`. Yet, when I supply that same existing number through the parameter for comparison with the field, the outcome is false.

My logic looks like this,

```
($F{EMPNO}==$P{eno})? "Hello":"Invalid."
```

Ideally, I expect the word 'Hello' to be printed when the value supplied through the parameter makes the condition true, and 'Invalid' to be printed when the condition is false.

Comment: as you will see in dupe you need to compare $F{EMPNO}.intValue()==$P{eno}.intValue()

Answer (score -1):

Try placing Boolean.valueOf infront of your parameter.
Boolean.valueOf($F{EMPNO}==$P{eno})? "Hello":"Invalid."

Comment: Hi, the outcome is still false.